# I wrote a nice program in linux and I don't want people to steal my work

Tags: linux, security, unix

I wrote a nice program in linux and I don't want people to steal my work, is there a way for me to hide the contents of my sh file from other people seeing it when I publish it? And it still has to be functional when I publish it to the public. I won't be posting any of the code because of this.

Comment: You can prevent people from stealing your Linux program the same way Linus has prevented you from stealing Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider adding an open source license to your program to protect it:

https://dzone.com/articles/selecting-an-open-source-license-for-your-project

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to compile the shell script to C and ship a binary executable. Compilers for the shell language exist, such as [CCsh](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/faqs/ccshlit.html) from Comeau Computing, which is a proprietary product, like yours.